# iptables clears itself

Tags: debian, iptables

So I'm having the strangest problem. I am currently being SYN flooded, so I wrote a script to track and `DROP` (via `iptables`) the IP's that were flooding me, but it didn't help, and the problem is that iptables flushes itself some every ten seconds it seems.

So I run the script, several rules are added and `iptables -L` shows them. Wait a few seconds and run `iptables -L` again and they're all gone.

I've obviously checked my crontabs for root and for the system, and nothing touches `iptables`, also, crontab runs as most every minute, and this is done much more often. I'm at a loss here, really. I've also turned on SYN cookies in sysctl

I'm running Debian 7.7 (wheezy) and I have a plan to upgrade, but I need to address this problem faster than I can upgrade.

Comment: Will syn cookies in sysctl help?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, already tried that

Comment: iptables is not supposed to flush alone. Are you activating/deactivating interfaces? In which ports are you being syn flooded?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I know it's not supposed to do this by itself, but it does. I am dropping packages on port 80

Comment: do you have any firewalling daemon? check which processes are running and which packages they come from.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist iptables isn't even a service in Debian 7.7, so I don't know what other "firewalling daemon" you maybe in reference to, I haven't installed any at least

Comment: Right.. and it's not that your script is run automatically/repeatedly and flushes iptables itself?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist No, and this happens if I add the rules manually as well :/

Comment: Please add the output from `ls /etc/init.d/` as background to the question; it would give some information about currently installed (enabled or disabled) services.

Comment: No idea if mod_evasive helps with syn floods, think not. I usually blocked those kind of things at the corporate firewall level.

Comment: I would be a bit worried that the system might have been hacked and rootkitted; the rootkit might include a task to auto-remove any iptables rules. If you suspect the system might have been hacked, [see this Canonical Question in Information Security.SE.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231)